# Incompatibile Slices in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, cpu, brainfuck

I am learning VHDL and for first project I picked up simple Brainfuck processor. When I try to compile it, I get error about incompatibile slices. I am using EdWinXP. How do I fix my code? Are there many mistakes in my code? Is there alternative of VHDL that would be simpler for C programmer?

```
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity BFCPU is
 port ( 
        I0 : in std_logic; --INPUT
        I1 : in std_logic; --PROGRAM
        I2 : in std_logic; --PROGRAM READY
        O1 : out std_logic; --PROGRAM NEEDED
        O2 : out std_logic; --OUTPUT
        O3 : out std_logic; --OUTPUT WRITTEN
        O4 : out std_logic); --INPUT NEEDED
        --O5 : out std_logic); --INPUT POOLING CLOCK
end BFCPU;

architecture work of BFCPU is
  type t_Memory is array (0 to 127) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
  signal rammem : t_Memory; 
  signal pointer : std_logic;
 begin
 pointer <= 0;
 workflow: process (I2) is
 begin
  if I1=1 then
    rammem(pointer) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(rammem(pointer)) + 1);
  elsif I1=2 then
    rammem(pointer) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(rammem(pointer)) - 1);
  elsif I1=3 then
    pointer <= pointer - 1;
  elsif I1=4 then
    pointer <= pointer + 1;
  elsif I1=5 then
    O2 <= rammem(pointer);
  elsif I1=6 then
    O4 <= not O4;
    inwait: while( I0 = 0 ) loop
        if not (I0 = 0) then
            rammem(pointer) <= I0;
        end if;
    end loop inwait;
    O4 <= not O4;
  end if;
 end process workflow;
end work;
```

Comment: Show us (a) the actual error message, (b) which line it's pointing to, and (c) your simulation testbench code, and (d) tell us if it worked in simulation. Taking a wild guess, you are slicing one of your arrays and the slice is the wrong size or datatype for the assignment target. You can't get away with mistakes like that in VHDL. (You can't get away with them in C either, it just takes much longer to find that out)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hcgnx4

Comment: For a start, the index type of `rammem` is effectively  `natural range 0 to 127;` i.e. a 7-bit unsigned (try declaring THAT in C :-) but you are trying to index it with a `std_logic` which is a single bit. If you can't see a problem with that, ... good luck.

Comment: I see... But, problem is there: `pointer <= 0;`, and which type should I use?

Comment: The same type as the index type of the array, of course. I'd declare `subtype index_t : natural range 0 to 127;` and declare things of that type, like `type t_Memory is array (index_t) of ...`  and `signal pointer : index_t;` and `for i in index_t loop ...` ... see how it works? Dont Repeat Yourself.

Comment: Now, i have such error: http://prntscr.com/hcgp9n, I'm newbie in this language, it seems different as I've never programmed in pascal/delphi...

Comment: You have a multiple sourced signal. `pointer` is assigned in and outside of the process. There can only be one source for a signal, except you use a resolved type like `std_logic` and the target platform and compiler supports that feature. In most cases that's not the case.

Comment: Btw. what kind of editor with integrated VHDL syntax checker and simulator do you use? Looking at Your Windows Version it's not even Windows 7, right? Is your VHDL tool as old as your Windows? You should use a modern VHDL simulator like e.g. [GHDL](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/releases). Such tools give you proper error messages.

Comment: If you don't like VHDL, why are you using it? If you want to program FPGA's of ASICs efficiently, you need to understand what is happening, so you need to program in a Hardware Description Language.

Comment: The [tag:brainfuck] tag has nothing to do with this question, as the question itself is in no way relevant to the brainfuck esoteric programming language, and that's why I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're writing below the begin statement and outside a process is always true, so this isn't sequential in any form. Imagine like an FPGA pin, which is soldered to ground.

You try to manipulate the pointer signal from within a process, but you can't because your pointer is fixed to '0'. 
If you want the pointer initializing to '0', as it looks like, you have to put this line within the process. However, i see you try to call arithmetic operations with the pointer signal, but you are defining the signal as std_logic. std_logic can represent '0', '1' and several other states, like High-Z, but not a number. You should take an integer or natural for calculations.